# How to create single Form for two models that are related by a Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I developed a voting system using Python and Django. I would like the user to be able to register new polls. However, when the user registers a new poll, it results in an IntegrityError. It looks like it can't get the ID of the first model. How do I fix this error? The photo of the error and the form is below...

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
     question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Date')
     show = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
     question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

forms.py

```
 from django.forms import ModelForm

 from .models import *


 class addPollsForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Question
         fields = ['question_text', 'pub_date', ]

 class addChoiceForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Choice
         fields = ['choice_text']
```

views.py

```
def addPollsPage(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        formAddPolls = addPollsForm()
        formAddChoice = addChoiceForm()
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            formAddPolls = addPollsForm(request.POST)
            formAddChoice = addChoiceForm(request.POST)
        
            if formAddPolls.is_valid():
                formAddPolls.save()
            if formAddChoice.is_valid():
                formAddChoice.save() 
        
            return redirect('votacao:index')

        context = {'formAddPolls': formAddPolls,
                   'formAddChoice': formAddChoice,
                  }
        return render (request, 'votacao/addPolls.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('main')
```

addPolls.html

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{formAddPolls.as_p}}
            {{formAddChoice.as_p}}
            {{formAddChoice.as_p}}
            {{formAddChoice.as_p}}
            <br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
```

[IntegrityError error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7hnG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the addChoiceForm dosn't have a question assigned. So, you need to add this manually.

```
if formAddPolls.is_valid():
    question = formAddPolls.save()
    if formAddChoice.is_valid():
        formAddChoice.question=question
        formAddChoice.save()
```

You can see also `inlineformset_factory`. Check this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) and here is an [example](https://techincent.com/explained-django-inline-formset-factory-with-example/).

Comment: Did not work. It returned this error: " name 'question' is not defined " . What am I missing?

Comment: @EduardoBrandão the reason you got that error is because `formAddPolls.is_valid()` return False so the variable wasn't set. Check to see why it's invalid

Comment: Also the second if statement should be inside the first if, i change the  asnwer for that.

Comment: Hi Eduardo. Firstly sorry for my english. Your answer code unfortunately still doesn't work. However, thanks to the example link you sent I managed to solve my problem. Thank you very much.